# How to add product into cart using routing in angular?

Tags: angular, routes, components

I have 4 child component out of which 3 are having arrayList each having few detail about the product like brand,model and price. Now i want to add this products into the 4th component i.e.cart List using add button in front of every product. For this i need to use routing.The name of 3 components are Mobile,Tv,Laptop.

You can get whole idea by https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulaar-tvcart-nedabx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.ts

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Why do you want to use the routing (with query parameter for example) and not a sevice ?

Comment: i am using service..but will need router also na for doing this??

Comment: @Wandrille you can get the whole idea by opening that link..while for instance i am just considering Mobile section..once it is done i'll apply the same for other two also.

Comment: to make it easy for u to understand...i just need to pass data to authService on pressing add button..and after that need to push that data into an arrayList in authService and display it..but i am not able to pass that data..to authService..
hope you are getting it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit messy but you can dot this:

in your `.html`, use the function add(c) on click.

```
<div class="col-4  bg-light ">{{c.brand}}</div>
<div class="col-4  ">{{c.model}}</div>
<div class="col-2 ">{{c.price}}</div>
<button class=" col-1 btn-primary" (click)="add(c)">ADD</button>
```

in your `.component.ts`, create the function add.

```
constructor(private cartService : CartService){}

add(product){
   this.cartService.add(product)
}
```

In your service `cart.service.ts` :

```
products = [];

add(product){
  this.products.push(product);
}

getProducts(){
  return this.products
}
```

and in your `cart.component.ts`:

```
products=[];

constructor(private cartService : CartService){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.products = this.cartService.getProducts()
}
```

Comment: thanks.! it did worked with some modification..but thanks for giving the idea